# Errors when importing SQL script to create a database for WSO2 cluster

Tags: wso2

When in mysql i import SQL script 'mysql_cluster5.7.sql' to create a database 'apimgtdb' for WSO2 IS 5.6.0 (IS as KM) Cluster, i receive errors:

```
- ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint 
- ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'apimgtdb.TABLENAME' doesn't exist.
```

What is wrong with SQL script for cluster?

When i import SQL script 'mysql5.7.sql' (not cluster version), everything is OK.

I use MySQL cluster 7.6 (NDB).

I tried to import SQL script from IS 5.6.0, i receive one type of errors, when i import SQL script from IS 5.7.0 i receive different types of errors.

Comment: the main diff between `mysql_cluster5.7.sql` and 
`mysql5.7.sql` is engine in create table statements. `ENGINE NDB` in cluster and `ENGINE INNODB` for non-cluster. just try to execute sql commands one-by-one, show which one fails

Comment: I know which tables fail, cause i launched WSO2 IS after that, it showed me what tables i don't have in DB. Problem in Foreign Key Constraint. I checked SQL syntax, it is OK. I checked fields in Tables, it types, it's OK. I don't know where is a problem.

Comment: So maybe your question to MySQL community... Show the SQL that failed and real error and ask why it so.